# Not able to get result out of my adjaceny matrix code for declaring graph

Tags: c, data-structures, graph

I have written acode for adjacency matrix for graph declaration. It compiles successfully with no errors. But when i run the code and entered the values, my code get crahes out only after reading the values of number of edges and vertex i.e v & e.
I am not able to input the values for *edges i.e u & v*. Need help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Graph
{
  int v;
  int e;
  int **Adj;
};

struct Graph *adjMatrixOfGraph()
{
  int i,u,v;
  struct Graph *G = (struct Graph *)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
  if(!G)
  {
    printf("Memory Error");
    return 0;
  }

  scanf("Number of Vertices:%d Number of Edges:%d",&G->v,&G->e);

  G->Adj = (int** )malloc(sizeof(G->v*G->v));
  G->Adj =(int **) malloc(G->v*sizeof(int*));
  for ( i = 0; i < G->v; ++i)
  {
    *(G->Adj+i) = (int*) malloc(G->v*sizeof(int));
  }

  for(u=0;u<G->v;u++)
  {
    for(v=0;v<G->v;v++)
    {
      G->Adj[v][v]=0;
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<G->v;i++)
  {
    scanf("Reading Edge:%d %d",&u,&v);
    G->Adj[u][v]=1;
    G->Adj[v][u]=1;
  }
  return G;
}

int main()
{
  int a;

  struct Graph *p = adjMatrixOfGraph();

  int u,v;
  p->Adj = malloc(sizeof(p->v*p->v));

  for(u=0;u<p->v;u++)
  {
    for(v=0;v<p->v;v++)
    {
      if(p->Adj[u][v]==1)
        printf("\n there is an edge from%d",u,"---------->%d",v);
    }
  }*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No compilation errors? Also no warnings?
`p->Adj = malloc(sizeof(p->v*p->v));`looks very strange and does not result in a value you might expect. At first glance `p->v*p->v` is an integer and its size is 4.
By assigning the memory location for this 4 bytes to p->Arr makes the formerly allocated memory unreachable and causes a memory leak.

Comment: yes, i havent get any compilation or warning.

Comment: @AjayKhetan.: check my answer and chang ethe scanf as I have said and also the edge in for loop..it will work.

Comment: Very interesting. I get warnings about implicit declaration of malloc and an error for invalid printf() function call.

Comment: @Gerhardh.: You have to correct those ofc but those are no big deal... the main problem is mentioned in my answer

Comment: i haven't included the #include<strdlib.h>, thats why warnings regarding implicit declaration of malloc() was coming. After by including it, there is no warning @Gerhardh

Comment: Your printf holds an error and your compiler should give a warning or even an error due to "Too many arguments for format string."   `printf("\n there is an edge from%d",u,"---------->%d",v);` you only have one format specifier %d but you provide 3 arguments: an int, a string and another int. When I throw this code at GCC I get an error for this printf call.

Comment: @Gerhardh - Why not add the `printf` bug as an answer? Together with a correction proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that this is the reason for your crash but you have a number of strange things in your code.

1) Always check scanf return value

```
if (scanf("Number of Vertices:%d Number of Edges:%d",&G->v,&G->e) != 2)
{
    // Add error handling
}
```

2) Memory leak

```
G->Adj = (int** )malloc(sizeof(G->v*G->v));
G->Adj =(int **) malloc(G->v*sizeof(int*));
```

Here you assign to `G->Adj` twice and thereby causes memory leak. Further the first allocation looks wrong as it doesn't use `sizeof` a type.

3) Scanned value not used, i.e. `G->e` is never used.

4) Strange index

```
for(u=0;u<G->v;u++)
{
    for(v=0;v<G->v;v++)
    {
        G->Adj[v][v]=0;
    }
}
```

Here you never use `u` for index. Should it be: `G->Adj[u][v]=0;`

5) Another memory leak in main

```
p->Adj = malloc(sizeof(p->v*p->v));
```

Again you overwrite `Adj` and causes memory leak. The `sizeof(p->v*p->v)` looks strange. Should it be `sizeof(int*)*p->v*p->v`? Further all initialization done in the function is lost. This means that you have undefined behavior when you start accessing data as `int`. Perhaps, you shouldn't at all do the `malloc` in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Use simple scanf..Dont get the "Give edges .." etc in scanf. Simply use `scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);`

```
for(i=0;i<G->v;i++)
{
    //scanf("Reading Edge:%d %d",&u,&v);
    if(scanf("%d %d",&u,&v)==2){//works
    ..
    }
     ...
}
```

***Otherwise scanf expects you to type those letters exactly from the standard input.***

```
for(i=0;i<G->e;i++)
{
    if(scanf("Reading Edge:%d %d",&u,&v)!=2){ //debug; }
    G->Adj[u][v]=1;
    G->Adj[v][u]=1;
}
```

Take edges not vertices number of inputs.

As 4386427..add a check in `scanf` .. it is good practice and effective one too.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what he does? Except for changing `G->v` to 'N' in your version?

Comment: OK. Now you've edited multiple times making my last comment obsolete. Your answer does not fix any of the memory leaks which sure cause problems.

Comment: I think it's likely that you are right, i.e. that OP only input 2 numbers instead of the whole text plus 2 numbers. Well spotted. But, please, add a check of the value returned by `scanf`. After all it was (probably) the missing check that caused the problems in the first place. Further, you could fix the second `scanf` and suggest a bounds check.

Comment: I have also check the scanf() part. It is returning 2, which means that scanf() has succefully read two values from console. @4386427

Comment: @AjayKhetan.: Use only "%d %d"...not those inputs...and ofc it will say 2 as it read 2 character only ..

Comment: @AjayKhetan.: when reading edges for loop will be upto `G->e`

Comment: @4386427.: Thanks

Comment: @Gerhardh.: Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This time we seem to need 3 answers. ;)
While 4386427 addresses the memory leaks and incorrect allocation style, Coderredoc addressed the wrong usage of scanf and loop variables.

Additionally printf is called incorrectly:

```
printf("\n there is an edge from%d",u,"---------->%d",v);
```

These are 3 arguments for 1 format specifier. It should be changed to

```
printf("\n there is an edge from %d---------->%d",u,v);
```

If you take care of all 3 answers your code should work.

Comment: These things probably help me to remove all sorts of error. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally, from going through all the suggestion made above, ihave updated my code to as below.But the problem persist.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//using namespace std;
struct Graph
{
    int v;
    int e;
    int **Adj;
};

struct Graph *adjMatrixOfGraph()
{

    int i,u,v;
    struct Graph *G = (struct Graph *)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    if(!G)
    {
        printf("Memory Error");
        return 0;
    }

    scanf("%d %d",&G->v,&G->e);


    G->Adj= malloc(G->v * sizeof(int *));


    for(i = 0; i < G->v; i++) {
    G->Adj[i] = malloc(G->v * sizeof(int));
}
    for(u=0;u<G->v;u++)
        {
            for(v=0;v<G->v;v++)
            {
                G->Adj[v][v]=0;
            }
        }

    for(i=0;i<G->v;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
        G->Adj[u][v]=1;
        G->Adj[v][u]=1;
    }
    return G;
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    int i;
    struct Graph *p = adjMatrixOfGraph();
   // printf("Number of Vertices:%d, Number of Edges:%d",p->v,p->e);
    int u,v;

    p->Adj= malloc(p->v * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < p->v; i++) {
    p->Adj[i] = malloc(p->v * sizeof(int));
    }

    for(u=0;u<p->v;u++)
        {
            for(v=0;v<p->v;v++)
            {
                if(p->Adj[u][v]==1)
                    printf("\n there is an edge from%d",u,"---------->%d",v);

            }
        }
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: You still don't check the return value of `scanf` - please add that check and update code.

Comment: You still throw away your allocated array and create a memory leak in main: `p->Adj= malloc(p->v * sizeof(int *));`   This was already allocated in `adjMatrixOfGraph()`

Comment: Actually i have done the for scanf(), and then remove that part, when i noticed it is working well.

Comment: ohh, sry.. that was by mistake. thanx @gerhardh

Comment: sry, couldn't upvote u for ur suggestions. I have less reputation.